# Task<Task> illegal in C#?

Tags: c#, multithreading, task

This code gives a **compile time error** in VS2015

> Error  CS0266  Cannot implicitly convert type 'System.Threading.Tasks.Task' to 'System.Threading.Tasks.Task<System.Threading.Tasks.Task>'. An explicit conversion exists (are you missing a cast?)

**UPDATE 1:** extended code after a Task instead of Task< Task > was suggested.

```
        int i = 0;

        Task<int> test = Task.Run( () => {
            return i;
        } );

        i = test.Result;

        Task t = Task.Run( () => { } );

        Task<Task> test2 = Task.Run( () => {
            return t;
        } );

        t = test2.Result;
```

What am I doing wrong?

**UPDATE 2:**
This code gives a **warning** (and I want no warnings and no suppress pragmas)

> Warning    CS1998  This async method lacks 'await' operators and will run synchronously. Consider using the 'await' operator to await non-blocking API calls, or 'await Task.Run(...)' to do CPU-bound work on a background thread.

```
        int i = 0;

        Task<int> test = Task.Run( () => {
            return i;
        } );

        i = test.Result;

        Task t = Task.Run( () => { } ); 

        Task<Task> test2 = Task.Run( async () => {
            return t;
        } );

        t = test2.Result;
```

**UPDATE 3:**

To all people insisting on `Task test2`.

1. `StartAndReturnSecondTaskAsync` must return the second task (executing `longOperation2`)
2. `StartAndReturnSecondTaskAsync` must be `async`, i.e. UI must not block for the duration of `longOperation1`

   ```
   public static async Task<Task> StartAndReturnSecondTaskAsync() {
       Task t = await Task.Run( () => {
           return StartAndReturnSecondTask();
       } );
       return t;
   }

   public static Task StartAndReturnSecondTask() {
       var importantData = longOperation1();
       return Task.Run( () => {
           longOperation2( importantData );
       } );
   }

   ...

   Task second = await StartAndReturnSecondTaskAsync();
   ```

Comment: Are you sure you *want* `Task<Task>`? What do you intend to use it for?

Comment: @Stephen Cleary Please see Update 3.

Comment: That doesn't explain why you need `Task<Task>` rather than just `Task`.

Comment: I need to await on the first task and return the second one

Comment: @PetSertAl Error CS0266 Cannot implicitly convert type 'System.Threading.Tasks.Task' to 'System.Threading.Tasks.Task<System.Threading.Tasks.Task>'. An explicit conversion exists (are you missing a cast?)

Comment: To Update #3: drop `async` and `await`: please do not mix Business logic and UI: `public static Task<Task> StartAndReturnSecondTaskAsync() { Task t = Task.Run(...` and only then `await StartAndReturnSecondTaskAsync();`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's an extremely common but to use `Task.Run` to perform some asychronous operation, and if using the older method `StartNew` it would do what you're expecting, which is to schedule a thread pool thread to *start* the asynchronous operation, and tell you when that asynchronous operation has finished *being started*.

This is, however, basically never what people actually want.  They want to know when the asynchronous operation called in `Task.RUn` *finishes*.  Because of this, `Task.Run` will unwrap any `Task<Task> that would be returned, so that what you're really seeing is the inner`Task`.

If you *really* do just want to have a thread pool thread *start* the task, and just know when it has finished being *started*, then you can use `Task.Factory.StartNew` which does not unwrap the `Task<Task>` on your behalf.

Comment: Are you trying to say that it's illegal because most people are too stupid to use it right? Can you post working code with Task.Factory?

Comment: @AntonDuzenko I'm not saying it's illegal, I'm saying that `Task.Run` unwraps tasks for you because most people who call `Task.Run` with a method that returns a `Task` would want it unwrapped.  Since that's what most people actually want to get back, that's what it does.

Comment: So I did it with *return await Task<Task>.Factory.StartNew()* but can it be done with less wording?

Comment: @AntonDuzenko Sure, you have no reason to do any of what you're actually asking in the first place.  Wrap the two long operations in calls to `Task.Run`, and `await` them.  Then you're just done `StartAndReturnSecondTaskAsync` doesn't need to exist at all, and `StartAndReturnSecondTask` is actually asynchronous, instead of returning a `Task` but doing half of its work synchronously, which it has no reason at all to do.

Comment: No, I mean, can I do "return await Task<Task>.Factory.StartNew()" with less wording? (I.e. without Factory)

Comment: @AntonDuzenko You can remove `<Task>`, if you really care about removing characters.

Answer (score 2):

`Task<Task>` are *quite common* and often a problem (if we erroneously wait/await *wrong*, *outer* task):

```
  int i = 0;

  Task<int> test = Task.Run(() => {
    return i;
  });

  Task t = Task.Run(() => {
  });

  // please, notice "async"
  Task<Task> test2 = Task.Run(async () => { // <- async: let insist on Task<Task>...
    return t;
  });
```

There's even an *extension method* for `Task<Task>`

```
  Task backToTask = test2.Unwrap();
```

In your case you want

```
  Task test2 = Task.Run(() => {
    return t;
  });
```

Since `Task.Run` calls `Unwrap()` for you

Comment: That works, but gives a warning: Warning CS1998 This async method lacks 'await' operators and will run synchronously. Consider using the 'await' operator to await non-blocking API calls, or 'await Task.Run(...)' to do CPU-bound work on a background thread. And I don't want to to add a suppress pragma.

Comment: @Anton Duzenko: just declare `Task test2 = Task.Run(() => {return t; });` and `Task.Run` will implicitly call `Unwrap` for you

Comment: Task test2 will give error on 
        t = test2.Result;

Comment: @Anton Duzenko: *Inner* `Task` (`t`) doesn't return anything, that's why  `test2.Result` (outer and *unwrapped*) doesn't return as well.

Answer (score 0):

A simple solution without getting into much details:

The code that would work would be:

```
int i = 0;
Task<int> test = Task.Run(() =>
{
    return i;
});
Task t = Task.Run(() => { });
Task test2 = Task.Run(() =>
{
    return t;
});
```

If you go with other possible approaches that use `await`, You would need to make the context `async`, like:

```
public async Task DoesTheThreadedOperations()
{
// Your code in question and other code
}
```

**As per your Update 3**

```
public static async Task StartAndReturnSecondTaskAsync()
{
    await Task.Run(() =>
    {
        return StartAndReturnSecondTask();
    });
}

public static Task StartAndReturnSecondTask()
{
    System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(5000);
    return Task.Run(() =>
    {
        System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(10000);
    });
}
```

I have used sleep to imitate your long operations. I hope you don't necessarily want to use `Task<Task>`. This should give you enough thrust to attack your scenario. You can further improve it to get your exact results by making these two operations two different threads and pass the results from one to other, await the one you want and run and leave the other longer task running without await. That is, call both methods from your main method, one awaited and other not.

Comment: Please see Update 1

Comment: @AntonDuzenko Did you notice the difference
`Task<Task> test2 = Task.Run(`
`Task test2 = Task.Run(`
. Update 3 however is bit different, let me see.

Comment: await StartAndReturnSecondTaskAsync() is void and does not return Task. Try this: Task second = await StartAndReturnSecondTaskAsync(). I get Error CS0030 Cannot convert type 'void' to 'System.Threading.Tasks.Task'